# Script that creates an active CSS on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that creates an active CSS on link, but I think there are a lot of `if` statements.  Can someone help me refactor this?

```
var link = window.location.pathname;
var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

var hl = $('#ih').val();



if (hl == 'True') {
    var currentPageName = 'WVD';
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("R") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("C") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}

if (location.pathname == "/") {
    var currentPageName = 'MD';
}

$(".main-navigation ul li a").each(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if (link.indexOf(currentPageName) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).css("color", "white");
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "bold");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with this? That way we can find other ways to do it. I'm pretty sure setting an `active` based on the url isn't this long.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider that using Javascript might not be the best solution. If you use something like PHP, passing a variable to the file generating the html setting which one is active is a cleaner solution.

Anyway..

First it seems that the following variable is unused and can be removed:

```
var link = window.location.pathname;
```

Then this line:

```
var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
```

will trigger an error if the url is root (http://www.example.com/)
and it's the same as in these ifs, which also can be combined to one:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("R") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("C") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}
```

which means that one of them is redundant and can be removed.

You can also remove `var` in all but the first  `var currentPageName`

An easier way to add the active effect would be to use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like this:

```
selector = '.main-navigation ul li a[href*="'+currentPageName+'"]"'
$(selector).css({
    'color': 'white',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
}).addClass('active');
```

This means that the complete code could look like this:

```
var match = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/);
var currentPageName = '';

if (location.pathname == '/') {
    currentPageName = 'MD';
} else if (match != null) {
    currentPageName = match[0];
}

var hl = $('#ih').val();

if (hl == 'True') {
    currentPageName = 'WVD';
}

selector = '.main-navigation ul li a[href*="'+currentPageName+'"]"'
$(selector).css({
    'color': 'white',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Txnaks only this one I have to added to maake it work if (window.location.href.indexOf("R") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("C") > -1) {
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}